# Image of a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra

For a linear function given by a Matrix $A$, the kernel is defined as

$ker(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax = 0\}$.

In my notes I have written that

$im(A)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid \exists y \colon x= y^T A\}$

This confuses me a lot, since I thought that

$im(A)=\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid \exists x \colon Ax=y\}$.

Is this the same or where is my mistake?

Comment: make up your mind in choosing for $x,\ y$ to be matrix-columns otherwise matrix-rows

Comment: So based on your comments, I am sure that the second defintion is the right one. But can you tell me where the first one Comes from? Because this is the one our lecturer mentioned.

Comment: the idea is that mixing it doesn't any good!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on janmarqz's comment, if $x,y$ are column vectors, then $Ax$ is a column vector, and $y^TA$ is a row vector.

(It would not make sense for $y$ to be a row vector since then $y^T$ would be a column vector and then $y^TA$ would not make sense as an operation)

So the image should be the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Herewith I am assuming $A:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$

So, $x\in \mathbb R^n\implies x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$

Now, The matrix $A$ will be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\ldots&a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}$

Now $Ax=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\ldots&a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}_{m\times n}
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times 1}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_m
\end{pmatrix}_{m\times 1}$

S0 the \begin{align}
im(A)&=\{ y\in \mathbb R^m: \text{ therexists } x\in \mathbb R^n \text{ s.t }Ax=y\}
\end{align}

Comment: it should be $
\left(\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\y_n\end{array}\right)$ at the end of line 4